# Display Flag By Country Script

Tags: php

I'm looking for a decent php script/snippet that can display a flag by the users' country with PHP. Surprisingly, there doesn't seem to be a decent/accessible solution for this.

Here's the idea:

1. Firstly, the flag images should condensed into a single sprite
2. The script would then zero in on the coordinates of the sprite based on the country code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for the right php manner to detect the language from the server variable such as $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the sprite over here : [Flag sprite](http://flag-sprites.com)